# Android how to make background Image of layout responsive?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I'm new to Android.

I'm creating a speedometer application and in that I want to attach specific image of meter as a background of digital text. I've attached the code which I wrote for preview.

I've attached image of desired Interface and image of my xml preview with it's code.

How to make layout more responsive?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="@color/background"
tools:context=".fragment.Tab2">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/digitalView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"

    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_text"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/speedTextDigital"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="00"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textSize="90sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/unit"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="KM/H"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**UI which I want to make :**

[image: This Image is UI which I want to make]

**UI which I am getting now :**

[image: This image is created by me but it's not responsive]

Comment: post your code and what you want to achieve

Comment: Please post your layout xml and desired and actual screens if possible.

Comment: I've posted code and original and desired Images

Comment: I don't think your approach will fit your needs, I'm afraid you should implement a custom view in order to make appropriate calculation within the speed arrow and the dashboard, otherwise you will fall into problems with different screen ratios. A starting point can be this repository: https://github.com/gkravas/MeterView

Comment: I've done with the analog view of speed. this gui is actually digital view..

Comment: I want to add image in the background of DigitalTextView...
and this image is not actually  responsive